Nextjs: Problem in Generate Static Pages with nextjs 14
I have a problem with my nextjs application which is, I have this
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
export const dynamicParams = true;

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const { data } = await fetch(
    `${process.env.DOMAIN}/api/product?getall=true&active=true`,
    { cache: "no-store" }
  ).then((res) => res.json());

  if (data.length === 0) {
    return [];
  }

  return data.map((item) => ({
    id: item._id,
  }));
}

async function getProduct(id) {
  const { data } = await fetch(`${process.env.DOMAIN}/api/product/${id}`, {
    next: { revalidate: 60 },
  }).then((res) => res.json());

  if (!data) {
    notFound();
  }

  return data;
}

export default async function ProductPage({ params }) {
  const data = await getProduct(params.id);
...
}

i get this error:


I would like to know how to properly implement the static generation of my product list without next build throwing me an error
how can I solve that?
I have tried updating nextjs from 13 to 14, but the problem still persists in this version too
